# GridAdapter always returns nullpointer exception during inflating process

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, layout-inflater

Hi i have the following code:

```
public class ContactGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Person> mPeople;
    private int mThumbs = R.drawable.default_photo_ic;

    public ContactGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> people){
        super(context, R.layout.grid_item_text);
        mContext = context;
        mPeople = people;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mPeople == null){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return mPeople.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Person getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mPeople.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_text, parent, false);

        TextView personName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        ImageView personThumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

        personName.setText(mPeople.get(position).fullName);
        personThumb.setImageResource(mThumbs);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Which is called from MainActivity within the onPostExecute like so..

```
*** REST OF CODE OMITTED ***
private class RetrieveFriendList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Person>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Person> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Person> friendList = null;
        String resultData = ((new HttpRetriever())).getFriends(myAccount.email, myAccount.passwd);
        Log.i("THUMBQOO", resultData);

        try {
            if(resultData != null){
                friendList = (new ContactHandlers()).friendList(resultData);
            }else{
                friendList = null;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("THUMBQOO - RET FRIEND", "JSON Exception");
        }

        return friendList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Person> result) {
        Log.i("THUMBQOO", result.toString());
        if(result != null){
            gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));
        }
    }
}
```

How ever i always get java.lang.NullPointerException on the gridView.setAdapter line above.

I have tried to remove the context reference within my adapter so my code looks like below:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_text, null);

        TextView personName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        ImageView personThumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

        personName.setText(mPeople.get(position).fullName);
        personThumb.setImageResource(mThumbs);
        return view;
    }
```

But i still get the same error.

I am sure that the ContactGridAdapter object is created, by printing some Log info from within the grid constructor.

The error is originating somewhere in the geView(), however i am not sure specifically where.

I also 100% sure that my ArrayList contains something. I have tried to Toast it like so people.get(0).ObjectVariable

Can anyone help me pointing to the right direction?

EDIT 1:

Here's an excerpt from my LogCat

```
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at com.gelliesmedia.thumbqoo.ContactActivity$RetrieveFriendList.onPostExecute(ContactActivity.java:239)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at com.gelliesmedia.thumbqoo.ContactActivity$RetrieveFriendList.onPostExecute(ContactActivity.java:1)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-13 11:17:05.971: E/AndroidRuntime(4722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 2:

Thank you all for the suggestion, however the problem persists.

For debugging purposes, here's what i did:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Person> result) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("");
        sb.append(result.size());
        String rSize = sb.toString();

        Log.i("THUMBQOO", result.toString());
        Log.i("THUMBQOO", rSize);
        Log.i("THUMBQOO", result.get(0).fullName.toString());


        /*
         * if(result != null){
            gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));
        }*/
    }
```

And this is what i get from my LogCat

- 12-13 11:49:23.316: I/THUMBQOO(6671):
  [com.gelliesmedia.thumbqoo.models.Person@a7446248,
  com.gelliesmedia.thumbqoo.models.Person@a7485d38] << FIRST LOG
- 12-13 11:49:23.316: I/THUMBQOO(6671): 2 << SECOND LOG
- 12-13 11:49:23.316: I/THUMBQOO(6671): andwxyz << THIRD LOG

It is basically shows that result is indeed not null.

Comment: Do post your logcat also.

Comment: can you please add your crash logs?

Comment: Are you sure in your `onPostExecute` method `result` is not null ? Do post your `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Yes i am 100% sure that "result" is not null. Beside i already have if condition to check whether result is null or not.

Comment: @username you have to initialize your arraylist<T> memory, i already post this solutiion. Try it.

Comment: @user406090 I tried your solution, but it does not work. Beside i assign my ArrayList<Person> from within my constructor.

Comment: @username55 Try to check the size of your `result` array in `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: I think `getApplicationContext()` in `gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));` can you try yourActivity.this instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @praveenSharma still no luck, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row ;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_text, null);

        TextView personName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        ImageView personThumb = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

        personName.setText(mPeople.get(position).fullName);
        personThumb.setImageResource(mThumbs);

    }else {
    row = (View) convertView;
    }
   return row;
 }
```

Comment: Hi tamilan, i already tried it. It does not work. Thx for trying though.

Comment: @username55 line number **239** in `ContactActivity.java` ple

Comment: @username55 have you initilize your `gridView`.

Comment: that line says gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));

Comment: @username55 if your initilize your `gridView` clearly then try like this also `gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(activity.this, result)); `

Comment: i did initialize my gridView in the MainActivity. I'll try your suggestion in a sec. Thx for replying

Comment: @username55 post your `ContactActivity.java`.  i guess something wrong in yout `Gridview` initilize

Answer (score 0):

dont set adapter in onpostexecute..

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));
```

try to set it outside it

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your arraylist in your `doInBackground` method. Also do not pass the null in your Adapter class if you do not get any data. It will obveiously return the null pointer.

Try out as below :

```
   try {
        if(resultData != null){
            friendList =new ArrayList<Person>();//declare your arraylist
            friendList = (new ContactHandlers()).friendList(resultData);
        }
      //else{
        //    friendList = null;
        //}
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("THUMBQOO - RET FRIEND", "JSON Exception");
    }
```

**EDITED:**

Change your `getView` method as below:

```
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view ;
        view =convertView;
        ViewHolder m_holder;
        if (view == null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_text, parent, false);
         m_holder = new ViewHolder();
        m_holder.personName = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        m_holder.personThumb = (ImageView) view .findViewById(R.id.iconItem);

       view.setTag( m_holder);    
    }else {
          m_holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

        m_holder.personName.setText(mPeople.get(position).fullName);
         m_holder.personThumb.setImageResource(mThumbs);
   return view;
 }

   private class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView personThumb ;
    private TextView personName;
}
```

Comment: @GrlsHu, your suggestion is worth a try. However it still throws the same error. Thx for posting.

Comment: I would suggest you to not to check for the null value in your adapter class's `getCount` method also.

Comment: @username55 Did  you try out with my solution ?

Comment: yup i put this  @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 1; and it still returns error. Thank you for your suggestion.
 }

Comment: Do like this `@Override
    public int getCount() {
            return mPeople.size();
         }`

Comment: @grlshu i tried that as well, but again it still returns the same error. I started to think that the problem is not with the result array. But rather on how the inflater. I might as well recode it from the begining and trace my step from there.

Comment: @GrlsHu i tried your last suggestion. But it again returns the same error. Anyway, i think you helped me enough. I am just gonna scrap this code. And start from the beginning. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Arrayadapter keeps its own list of Person. Pass people as at third arg in the super ctor and then get of mPeople, getCount and getItem ..or just call their supers

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you.

I think the problem is in gridView object check wheather it is null or not if null than restart you Aynctask  after assign value to it 
like

```
  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Person> result) {

     try{
    Log.i("THUMBQOO", result.toString());
    if(result != null){
        gridView.setAdapter(new ContactGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));

     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
       //  your code for  grid view if it is null than restart Asyctask or regenerate 
       //     gridview object
      }
    }
```

Let me know if any help you need